# Image not display well when added more than 2 same cells (dynamic tableView)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

With my system I build my cell programmatically and set what I need in the cell compared to my array (data source of my tableView).

The problem appear when I add 3 cells or more on my tableView. The text is good but the image does not appear in the correct cell. I think this is a problem of the cache of the TableView system (reuse). I follow several post in this forum to fix that but nothing work.

This is my code in `cellForRowAt` :

```
let waitingCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"waiting", for: indexPath) as! CardCellWaiting
var cellToReturn : UITableViewCell!
let currentSurvey = user.lobbySurvey[indexPath.row]
let state : UserSurvey.state = currentSurvey.stateSurvey
switch state{
case .surveyWaiting:
    cellToReturn = waitingCell
    waitingCell.drawCard() // draw the card programmatically if needed
    waitingCell.clearImage() // look below to see the function
    waitingCell.setId(id: currentSurvey.id)
    waitingCell.setImage(image : currentSurvey.picture)
    waitingCell.setTimeLeft(timeLeft: currentSurvey.timeLeft)
    waitingCell.delegate = self
    waitingCell.delegateCard = self
}
return cellToReturn
```

this is how I update my source data (lobbySurvey) an array who contain User Survey classes. I build my cells since this one.

```
user.lobbySurvey.remove(at: 0)
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)
let surveyWaiting = UserSurvey(stateOfSurvey: .surveyWaiting)
surveyWaiting.picture = image
if let url = json["imageUrl"].string {
    surveyWaiting.pictureUrl = url
}
if let timeLeft = json["timeLeft"].string {
    surveyWaiting.timeLeft = timeLeft
}
if let surveySelfId = json["surveySelfId"].string {
    surveyWaiting.id = Int(surveySelfId)
}
let rowToInsert = self.getRowToInsert(typeOfState: .surveyWaiting)
user.counterSurvey += 1
user.lobbySurvey.insert(surveyWaiting, at: rowToInsert)
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: rowToInsert, section: 0)], with: .fade)
```

this is the `clearImage` function :

```
func clearImage(){
    surveyWaiting.imageEmptyView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backgroundEmptyImage")
}
```

and my `setImage` function :

```
func setImage(image : UIImage){
    surveyWaiting.imageEmptyView.image = image.resized(targetSize: CGSize(width:100,height:125))
}
```

I've try to empty my imageView like :

```
surveyWaiting.imageEmptyView.image = nil
```

But it doesn't work. I've also try to use a framework like [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke) with the url of the image, but nothing.

Why does my code not order the image in the good cell?

Comment: If **currentSurvey.picture** image data is downloaded to _model_ already, then what is the need to clear the image again ?

Comment: @Sateesh Cause the image is not good so I show you the code that I tried to do but it still does not work

Comment: @El-Burritos someone might be able to help you if you share more details on your code, ViewController, TableViewCell etc. It might be possible that `currentSurvey.picture` returns the same image.

Comment: @Satish Thanks, I add some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my mistake... I use this [framework](https://github.com/KyoheiG3/DynamicBlurView) to draw async blur to my imageView, but this plugin keep cache of the image who have blur.. So I just remove the cache of the blur and this solve the problem.